# start with Scala, intelliJ IDEA and SBT,can't found the run class menu

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

[image]

how can i run Hello scala Hello class? i can't find the Run menu.

Comment: Do you have the main defined?

Comment: /**
 * Created by qk on 15-5-2.
 */
class Hello extends App{
  println("hello")
}

Comment: thanks。i should create a object no a class

Answer (score 4):

Change `class Hello` to `object Hello`.